# SQL only returns sum for ids with multiple occurences

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

So I have three tables (AcDD, AH, Life) with multiple amounts per customer. A customer can have any combination of types. I created a query for each table to sum the Amounts of each AcDD, AH and Life. Then I created a fourth query combining all of them together. The problem is that I am only getting IDs that all 3 queries have in common...a customer might only have Life and no AcDD or AH--this ID is missing from my fourth query. What am I doing wrong?

Query by table(the same query exists for each of the three tables):

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID], 
       Sum([NewB-Coverage: AH].[AH Monthly Benefit]) AS [Sum Of AH Monthly Benefit]
FROM [Customers-Personal] INNER JOIN [NewB-Coverage: AH] 
ON [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID] = [NewB-Coverage: AH].[Customer ID]
GROUP BY [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID];
```

4th query (combining all)

```
SELECT [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID], 
       Sum_AcDD.[Sum Of AcDD Amount], 
       Sum_AH.[Sum Of AH Monthly Benefit], 
       Sum_Life.[Sum Of Decr Life Amount], 
       Sum_Life.[Sum Of Level Life Amount]
FROM Sum_Life INNER JOIN 
              (Sum_AH INNER JOIN 
                      (Sum_AcDD INNER JOIN [Customers-Personal] 
                                ON Sum_AcDD.[Customer ID] = [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID]) 
                      ON Sum_AH.[Customer ID] = [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID]) 
              ON Sum_Life.[Customer ID] = [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use LEFT (or RIGHT) joins.  INNER JOINS require that matching records exists in all tables.  A LEFT join specifies that *all records* from the left table should be returned.  For rows that do not match in the right table, null values are returned.  (A RIGHT join does exactly the same thing but just swaps relative positions of the table names. Common practice is to always order the tables such that you only use LEFT joins, but it's not a requirement.)

See [LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198084.aspx) which is specific to MS Access.

Redo of the 4th query.  I lazily used RIGHT joins just to keep the original ordering of the tables:

```
SELECT [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID], 
       Sum_AcDD.[Sum Of AcDD Amount], 
       Sum_AH.[Sum Of AH Monthly Benefit], 
       Sum_Life.[Sum Of Decr Life Amount], 
       Sum_Life.[Sum Of Level Life Amount]
FROM Sum_Life RIGHT JOIN 
          (Sum_AH RIGHT JOIN 
              (Sum_AcDD RIGHT JOIN [Customers-Personal] 
                        ON Sum_AcDD.[Customer ID] = [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID]) 
              ON Sum_AH.[Customer ID] = [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID]) 
          ON Sum_Life.[Customer ID] = [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID];
```

Comment: @C Perkins, thank you for your help, detailed explanation and link, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to tackle this.  The main thing to keep in mind is your join type.  Make sure to retain your *[Customers-Personal].[Customer ID]* column and Left Join from that table.

```
SELECT 
 [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID]
,Sum_AcDD.[Sum Of AcDD Amount]
,Sum_AH.[Sum Of AH Monthly Benefit]
,Sum_Life.[Sum Of Decr Life Amount]
,Sum_Life.[Sum Of Level Life Amount]
FROM 
[Customers-Personal] 
LEFT JOIN Sum_AcDD ON [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID] = Sum_Life.[Customer ID]
LEFT JOIN Sum_AH   ON [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID] = Sum_AH.[Customer ID]
LEFT JOIN Sum_Life ON [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID] = Sum_Life.[Customer ID]
```

Comment: @ Andrew, thanks for response but this didn't work. I got an error message: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID] = Sum_Life.[Customer ID] LEFT JOIN Sum_AH ON [[Customers-Personal].[Customer ID] = Sum_AH.[Customer ID] LEFT JOIN Sum_Life ON [[Customers-Personal].[Customer ID] = Sum_Life.[Customer ID].....not sure if it has anything to do with Left Join on Sum AcDD being set to Sum_Life.[Customer ID]...not sure if it has to do with LEFT JOIN Sum_AcDD ON [Customers-Personal].[Customer ID] = Sum_Life.[Customer ID] but @C Perkins solution worked.